# What is js DOM module and how to import it? Looking for context2d function

Tags: javascript

I'm learning d3 and React and I'm trying to recreate the following visualisation:

https://observablehq.com/@d3/mona-lisa-histogram

But I am completely stuck on the following piece of code:

```
const context = DOM.context2d(width, height, 1);
  context.willReadFrequently = true;
```

I understand that `context2d` gives us information about the pixels within the "canvas" of width and height. But I need help with basics: where do I import the DOM from? I cannot find anything about it, as any search links to discussion on what DOM is. Can someone help please?

Comment: https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib and https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib#dom is what a simple Google search turns up.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you! And I am glad it was simple for you but I was really stuck. Can you tell me what search query you used to find it? Maybe that will help me to not ask such questions here again in the future! Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Malvinka probably "observablehq DOM"

Comment: Ah, I haven't added "observablehq" to my search query. Thank you!